# javascript variable disappearing inside of promise results

Tags: javascript, variables, promise, scope

A head scratcher here.  I am defining a variable before calling a promise, then in the promise the variable is disappearing and showing as `undefined` causing an error in the script:

```
function xmlHTTP (url,params) {
  return new Promise( function(resolve) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'json' ;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
          resolve(xhr.response[0]) ;
        } else {
          var badCall = {status:false,errCode:xhr.status,errMsg:"XMLHttp Request failed to execute properly"} ;
          resolve(badCall) ;
        }
      }     
    }
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache') ;
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Expires', -1) ; 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate') ;
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json') ;
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'com.mydomain') ;
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Token') ;
    xhr.send(params);        
  }) ;
}
  function ge(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id) ;
  }

  function giveAward(chrID,uid) {
    var el = ge('awardID_' +chrID) ;
    var awInfo = ge('awardInfo_'+chrID) ;
    console.log(el) ;  // prints the element
    console.log(awInfo) ;  // prints the element
    var conf = confirm("Press OK to confirm giving out the award") ;
    var url = "xmlMembers.php" ;
    var params = JSON.stringify({typeID:1,chrID:chrID,uid:uid}) ;
    if (conf == false) {
      return ;
    } else {
      xmlHTTP(url,params).then(function(res) {
        if (res.status == true) {
          console.log(el) ;  // prints the element  
          console.log(awInfo) ;  // prints "undefined" 
          el.style.color = "green" ;  // this is working
          awInfo.style.color = "green" ;  // errors here because awInfo is undefined.
        }
      }) ;
    }
  }

<button id="awardButton_21843" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.0);" title="Give Award" onclick="giveAward(21843,'20220523_576943860');"><i id="awardIcon_22304" class="iconHandR icon-thumb-down"></i></button>
```

The above is printing to console:

```
> <td id=​"awardID_21843" style=​"color:​ green;​">"Kool Koozie "<br>​<span style=​"color:​red">​2022-10-20​</span>​</td>​
> <span style=​"color:​red" id=​"awardInfo_21843">​Expires: Never​</span>​
> <td id=​"awardID_21843" style=​"color:​ green;​">"Kool Koozie "<br>​<span style=​"color:​red">​2022-10-20​</span>​</td>​
> undefined
```

`el` is still defined inside the promise, but why isn't `awInfo` still defined? what's causing it get set to null?

Comment: There is nothing in your question's information that can explain why `awInfo` would have returned to `undefined`. Please provide enough (but minimal) code to make it reproducible.

Comment: @trincot - thats the problem....that IS the exact function.  I added more to the OP but I don't see anything in the extra function or the button call that would be causing this.

Comment: I pasted the code in my editor, and the code doesn't run. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Try changing `var awInfo =` into `const awInfo =`, to ensure it's not changed by some other code. Also ensure that this is the only declaration of an `awInfo` variable in your code.